# A link of a Jekyll page to its corresponding github page?

Tags: url, jekyll

How could one make it so that a page on Jekyll links to its corresponding page on GitHub?

For example, if the pages are of the form `www.example.org/restOfUrl`, and corresponding github entry is `github.com/example-org/example-project/restOrUrl.md`, how would one insert a link to the github page from the website?

Comment: What's wrong with something like `<a href="github.com/example-org/example-project/restOrUrl.md">some text</a>`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful well I want it to be automatic (there are a lot of pages). In particular, it's based on a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables):

> **page.path**
>
> The path to the raw post or page. Example usage: Linking back to the page or post’s source on GitHub. This can be overridden in the YAML Front Matter.

So you can use `{{ page.path }}` in your liquid code to get the information.